# How to split by comma vaules from varibale in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to get values from a variable. That variable has a lot of values. I want to get all the values by for loop and length. I tried the following but it is not working.

```js
var values = Test1,Test2,Test3,Test4,Test5;
values = values.split(',');
var valueList = [];
for (var i = 0; i <= values.length; i++) {
  valueList.push(values[i]);
}

console.log(valueList.length);
console.log(valueList);
```

How to resolve this issue?

Comment: `i<=values.length` Change this to `i<values.length` since array's index starts with 0.

Comment: split returns array itself why would you repeat which is already done?

Comment: what is `Test1,Test2,Test3,Test4,Test5;` ? Having this standalone (ie: not as a string) will cause errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an example if you need to do something with values from your `values` variable. As a result you will get a new array of strings.

```js
var values ="Test1,Test2,Test3,Test4,Test5"; 
    var newValues = values.split(',').map((item, index) => {
        return `Item at index ${index} is ${item}`;
    });
  
    console.log(newValues);
```

Comment: How to make array values agian like var new =="Test1,Test2,Test3,Test4,Test5";

Comment: It'w necessary to iterate through the array, parse each string an create a new array by map() function.

Comment: something like
newValues.map(item => {
const strVal = item.split(' ');
return strVal[strVal.length];
})

Answer (score 2):

The `split` function returns an array of values based on the delimiter provided, In your case it is comma , no need to store the values in another array

```js
var values ="Test1,Test2,Test3,Test4,Test5".split(',');
console.log(values);
console.log(values.length);
```

Comment: Not working..Actually my values is like this values =Test1,Test2,Test3,Test4,Test5 So I can not split the values

Comment: var values = Test1,Test2,Test3,Test4,Test5; this will surely produce a error

Comment: Values is returning by like this values = Test1,Test2,Test3,Test4,Test5 So split is not working for me..How we can convert as a string and split?

Comment: sry but, see your console for reference err

Answer (score 0):

You don't need any additional loops.According to [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) your current variable `values` already contains array with all your values.

```js
var values ="Test1,Test2,Test3,Test4,Test5"; 
values = values.split(',');

console.log(values);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a trailing semi-colon, you can split by a comma (`,`), and then `.filter` on your resulting array to only include truthy values (ie: non-empty strings) in your resulting array.

```js
const values = "Test1;Test2;Test3;Test4;Test5;";
const res = values.split(';').filter(Boolean);
console.log(res);
console.log(res.length);
```